# Make a HTML form in random order when refreshing

Tags: html, random

How do I make a HTML form in a random order? This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Welke game heeft géén multiplayer?</span>
                <select name="geen_multiplayer">
                    <option selected disabled>Maak een keuze</option>
                    <option>Red Dead Redemption 2</option>
                    <option>Destiny 2</option>
                    <option>South Park: The Fractured but Whole</option>
                    <option>FIFA 18</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>


        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Welke game is door Rockstar Games gemaakt?</span>
                <select name="gemaakt_rockstar">
                    <option selected disabled>Maak een keuze</option>
                    <option>Star Wars Battlefront II</option>
                    <option>The Elder Scrolls Online: Morrowind</option>
                    <option>Destiny 2</option>
                    <option>Red Dead Redemption 2</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Wat is géén shooter?</span>
                <select name="geen_shooter">
                    <option selected disabled>Maak een keuze</option>
                    <option>Red Dead Redemption 2</option>
                    <option>Destiny 2</option>
                    <option>Call of Duty: WWII</option>
                    <option>Star Wars Battlefront II</option>
                </select>
            </label>
```

So these are 3 questions. I would like to make it so that when you refresh the page, the questions will be in a random order. 
I am also using python, but I don't if I need that to make it random. I am accesing the form like this in python:

```
if (request.form["gemaakt_rockstar"] == "Red Dead Redemption 2"):
    score += 1
```

Is there a way to make these questions in a random order? Do I need python or something else?

EDIT: I already tried this code, but it doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/U8QxgtGy

Comment: What did not work of the code you tried? You can generate a random number and get the options out of an array based on that number. You can do that in any language you like.

Comment: The code just didn't do anything. When I use this: https://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/awJLJx, it works. But when I use it with pythonanywhere.com (I only use the HTML file) it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't sound like a programmer. If you need help with code from here you will at least need to be able try point what code is not work. It's also very easy to write the script yourself if you know a little about code. Also im not familiar with pyton anywhere (I hate pyton) but the code you linked is javascript.